# Does autofocus feature work on Nikon D5500 using the Tamron AF 70-300 F4-5.6 DI LD macro for Nikon?

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, tamron

I wanted to know if autofocus mode works on Nikon D5500 whilst using the Tamron AF 70-300mm F4-5.6 DI LD macro lens for Nikon?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will.  The D5500 does not have an autofocus (AF) motor in the body, so only lenses which have AF motors built-in will autofocus on that camera body.  But the Tamron AF 70-300mm *does* have an AF motor, so it will autofocus on the D5500.

Answer (score 0):

It depends :

The 70-300mm is available with a built-in motor (Model A17NII) from apx. February 2008. The A17N model which had been available up until February 2008 is only compatible with the D5500 in the MF mode due to the fact it doesn´t have a built-in motor.